# Why is my Resque job showing up as a DirtyExit even though it succeeds in doing it's job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, resque

We have a scheduled job in resque which runs every morning at 06:00.

The script runs three different SQL-queries, two of which are quick (10-15 sec) and one heavy one (~12 min). After finishing each query it converts the resulting ActiveRecord to a csv in a Tempfile and then writes the csv to a file in an S3 bucket.

The job works fine, the files end up in S3 like expected, but for some reason the job still ends up in resques list of failed jobs with a dirty exit status.

What is marking it as failed and why?